# No animation after 250th frame

Tags: animation, physics

Iam new to blender. Iam making a dominoes falling animation.
I have set start frame 1 and end frame 350 but after 250th frame it stops falling and there is no animation happening

Comment: What are you using to make the dominoes fall (physics properties)? Often, there is a separate set of bake settings based on the physics you are using (ie: Softbody has it's own bake cache).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yes Iam using physics properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of rigid body simulations depends on the Cache.

In the Scene Properties > Rigid Body World open the controls for cache and set the start and end to suit your needs.

[image]